# How to describe the interface of a simple Just functor in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a simple interface in typescript for the first time and having doubts about pretty much everything.

The question is simple. How to describe this simple jest matcher extension?

```typescript
/**
 * @param {*} v Any value
 */
function just (v) {
  return {
    fmap: f => just(f(v))
  }
}

expect.extend({
  /** Compare the two values inside two functors with Object.is
   * @method
   * @augments jest.Matchers
   * @param {*} actual The functor you want to test.
   * @param {*} expected The functor you expect.
   */
  functorToBe(actual, expected) {
    const actualValue = getFunctorValue(actual)
    const expectedValue = getFunctorValue(expected)
    const pass = Object.is(actualValue, expectedValue)
    return {
      pass,
      message () {
        return `expected ${actualValue} of ${actual} to ${pass ? '' : 'not'} be ${expectedValue} of ${expected}`
      }
    }
  }
})

test('equational reasoning (identity)', () => {
  expect(just(1)).functorToBe(just(1))
})
```

I have tried this but not sure about the generic types at all:

```typescript
import { Matchers } from 'jest'

interface Functor<T> {
  (value?: any): {
    fmap: (f: value) => Functor<T>
  }
}

interface Matchers<R> {
  functorToBe(actual: Functor<T>, expected:  Functor<T>): R
}
```

Ref: [JSDoc document object method extending other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972275/jsdoc-document-object-method-extending-other-class)

The gist of the jest type definition for `Matchers<R>`:

```typescript
/**
 * The `expect` function is used every time you want to test a value.
 * You will rarely call `expect` by itself.
 */
interface Expect {
    /**
     * The `expect` function is used every time you want to test a value.
     * You will rarely call `expect` by itself.
     *
     * @param actual The value to apply matchers against.
     */
    <T = any>(actual: T): Matchers<T>;
    /**
     * You can use `expect.extend` to add your own matchers to Jest.
     */
    extend(obj: ExpectExtendMap): void;
    // etc.
}
```

Well, this is confusing. The only *index.d.ts* in the jest repo is https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-editor-support/index.d.ts but that is not the one I get in vscode, which is https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jest/index.d.ts#L471.

Comment: In `functorToBe(actual: Functor<T>, expected:  Functor<T>)` I want to say that `actual` and `expected` must be the same type.

Answer (score 2):

### The extension

Your merge of `Matchers` is almost right, but from looking at the jest types on Definitely Typed [1], I can see that `Matchers` is nested inside a `jest` namespace. The part of the Typescript handbook that covers this is  [namespace merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

```
namespace jest {
    export interface Matchers<R> {
        functorToBe<T>(actual: Functor<T>, expected:  Functor<T>): R;
    }
}
```

When I tested this, I needed a tsconfig.json to get my JS files to see the declaration:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "test.js",
        "extensions.ts",
    ]
}
```

A jsconfig.json is almost the same thing, but doesn't require you to add `"allowJs": true` explicitly. But note that adding a tsconfig or jsconfig will turn off automatic downloads of types from Definitely Typed, and you'll have to manually `npm install @types/jest` (plus any other types for libraries you use). If you don't want to add a tsconfig, I was able to manually add a reference in the JS file as the first line:

```
/// <reference path="./extensions.ts" />
```

### The type of the new method

It should be something like:

```
functorToBe(expected: R): R;
```

Here is where things get confusing to me. Let me know if you have questions about this part of the problem and I will try to help.

Comment: [jest](https://jestjs.io/) is not something you import  and is only used for tests, not in the shipped code. How do I specify the type in argument T? Do I document `just` and then the typescript parser will figure it out? Anyway, mixing typescript and js seems like it needs more work. Currently, I can not import `jest`, since it is not how it works, and renaming myExtensions.d.ts to myExtensions.js gives me a lot of errors. Looks like I'm supposed to use JSDoc which can not handle this use-case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082859/205696

Comment: You have shadowed `T`

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood your problem entirely. I thought that (1) jest uses modules because of your import statement and (2) jest shipped its own types. I'll edit this answer to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nathan. I tried again just now to get the typescript checker to recognise my matcher but to no aval. Here is my effort, if you could be so kind to take a look when you have time: https://github.com/dotnetCarpenter/SO_jest_functor_ts

Comment: The current docs for Jest 26.1 https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers is mentioning `declare global {` but vscode 1.46.1 tells me that "Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.ts(2669)", though I do not know what that means.